# detecting type of generics within generics

Tags: c#

I have a method which accepts many different types of objects for storage:

```
public void Store<T>(T item)
{
    // works fine
    if (item is Foo)
    {
      // ...
    }
    // works fine
    else if (item is Observation<ImageSignal>)
    {
      // ...
    }

    // isn't detected
    else if (item is Observation<Signal<ISpectrum>>)
    {
      // ...
    }

    else 
    {
      // Observation<Signal<ISpectrum>> always hits this.
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can detect this?

**EDIT:**  I was actually passing in an object which wraps this object. Eric was right. Problem solved. Thanks for the quick responses, however.

Comment: My guess would be that the item isn't actually of type `Observation<Signal<ISpectrum>>` but really of type `Observation<Signal<SomeClassThatImplementsISpectrum>>`

Comment: Weird, for me your code works fine. item is Observation<Signal<ISpectrum>> = true

Comment: @Tuizi - curious if you are using .NET 4 or an older version?

Comment: @Eric I've also tried detecting based on the concrete class, which is Spectrum.

Comment: @EricPetroelje: I tried on an Winform application in .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and I don't get exception

Comment: Is item null?  Regardless of the type of T, if item is null, `item is [SomeType]` will return false.

Comment: As others mentioned, .Net 4 changes the way how covariance and contravariance are supported, especially when it comes to generic interfaces.

Comment: I actually had passed in a wrapper object which held this item.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

In this case wouldn't it be better to overload the `Store` function? It would be much easier to follow the logic.

```
public void Store(Foo item)
{
}

public void Store(Observation<ImageSignal> item)
{
}

public void Store(Observation<Signal<ISpectrum>> item)
{
}
```

Comment: @Magnus normally I would agree with you, but I'm replacing a DB4O data layer with a SQL data layer.  I need to maintain the existing interface.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(T)` or `item.GetType()`. hth